# Get relative path to the package.json where a script was called from

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm creating an npm package. Let's say a user installs this package. This means it will save to `project/node_modules/myPackage/`

Let's say I have various scripts within `myPackage` that can be located anywhere within `project/node_modules/myPackage/`. For example:

```
project/
  - node_modules/
    - myPackage/
      - script1.js
      - folder2/
        - script2.js
        - folder3
          - script3.js
```

These scripts are saved in `project/node_modules/myPackage/package.json` under `bin`, so they can be used in `project/package.json` under `scripts`.

Within each of those `script[n].js` files, I want to be able to get the path to `project/package.json`, which is where the script is called from.

For example, let's say I have the following in `project/package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "myPackage --build"
}
```

I'm looking for code similar to:

```
const pathToProjectRoot = // some code here to find the root
```

Once I run `npm run build` in the `project/` directory, this should return something similar to:

- `../../` for `script1.js`
- `../../../` for `script2.js`
- `../../../../` for `script3.js`

Comment: Use [`process.cwd`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_cwd) and resolve the path with [`path.resolve`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_resolve_paths)... ?

Comment: I've heard process.cwd isn't reliable as it depends on the directory of where the script was launched from, but now that I think about it I don't see any reason why users would need to run the script from anywhere besides their current working directory. I'll give it a go. Thanks.

Comment: I thought that was your question tbh :) glad it works then